# Getting derived key with CCKeyDerivationPBKDF

Tags: .net, swift, aes, pbkdf2

I have a problem with getting a pseudo-random generated derived key by using `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF` .

Here is the code I'm using by @zaph :

```
//    password     password String
//    salt         salt Data
//    keyByteCount number of key bytes to generate
//    rounds       Iteration rounds
//    
//    returns      Derived key


func pbkdf2SHA1(password: String, salt: Data, keyByteCount: Int, rounds: Int) -> Data? {
    return pbkdf2(hash:CCPseudoRandomAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1), password:password, salt:salt, keyByteCount:keyByteCount, rounds:rounds)
}

func pbkdf2SHA256(password: String, salt: Data, keyByteCount: Int, rounds: Int) -> Data? {
    return pbkdf2(hash:CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256), password:password, salt:salt, keyByteCount:keyByteCount, rounds:rounds)
}

func pbkdf2SHA512(password: String, salt: Data, keyByteCount: Int, rounds: Int) -> Data? {
    return pbkdf2(hash:CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA512), password:password, salt:salt, keyByteCount:keyByteCount, rounds:rounds)
}

func pbkdf2(hash :CCPBKDFAlgorithm, password: String, salt: Data, keyByteCount: Int, rounds: Int) -> Data? {
    let passwordData = password.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
    var derivedKeyData = Data(repeating:0, count:keyByteCount)

    let derivationStatus = derivedKeyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {derivedKeyBytes in
        salt.withUnsafeBytes { saltBytes in

            CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(
                CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),
                password, passwordData.count,
                saltBytes, salt.count,
                hash,
                UInt32(rounds),
                derivedKeyBytes, derivedKeyData.count)
        }
    }

    if (derivationStatus != 0) {
        print("Error: \(derivationStatus)")
        return nil;
    }



    return derivedKeyData
}
```

My problem is that it keeps generating the same derived keys for each call.
I am trying to decrypt the data that was encrypted on .Net side with the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`:

```
var saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Inputkey, saltBytes);

var aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);   // default keySize 256
aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8);  // default blockSize 128
```

On the .Net side, the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` returns new random set of bytes, but my Swift code is only generating for each call the same sequence.
What is wrong with that sequence generation on Swift side?

Edit1: When I used the bytes sequences of Key and IV generated by `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` from .net in Swift trying to decrypt the data encrypted in .net, then it works fine.

Edit2: Ok, I have found out that the first time the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` works with GetBytes method is the same result as on the Swift PBKDF2 result. The second call GetBytes gives a completly different result. Why is that? If I will solution for this, then my decryption should work.

```
aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);   // (1) - the same result as in Swift implementation
aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8);  // (2) - completly different result
```

Am I initializing the IV in Swift wrongly?

Comment: You need to use a different salt each time in production. The same IV needs to be used in encryption and decryption, one common method to accomplish this is tp prefix the encrypted data with the IV, it does not need to be secret. In the case of aesAlg.IV the function was initialized once and two calls made to it. It is a security problem to use the same IV with the same key more than once.

Comment: @zaph Thank you very much for your reply. Excuse me, I still don't getting it. Is the IV always of length 16 bytes for AES256? Do you mean, that the GetBytes method should not be called twice on the same instance? I may ask silly questions because I am new in this topic.

Comment: The AES IV is always 16-bytes. It needs to e different for every use of the same encryption key. It is best passed for decryption as part of the encrypted data, often pre-pended to the encrypted data. It does not matter what the IV is as long as it is random. If a method is used that generates the same IV for the same key that is not secure.

Comment: @zaph thank you for your time and explanation. I think that I am aware how it works now. My problem now is how to generate the IV the same way it is generated on C# with `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` in Swift. The other way is to pass the IV as a prepended to the encrypted data as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET implementation is effectively a stream. To get an equivalent answer from the Apple version you should ask for the total bytes you need in one call, then split it up into whatever pieces you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will check that.